# Fakebold not working on mathbb fonts

Tags: xetex, fontspec

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{latinmodern-math.otf}[FakeBold=4]

\let\mathbbalt\mathbb
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}[FakeBold=4]
\let\mathbb\mathbbalt

\begin{document}

    \begin{align*}
        v & \in\mathbb{V}\\
        f & \in\mathbb{F}
    \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

This is the output.

[image: Output]

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{latinmodern-math.otf}[FakeBold=4]

%\let\mathbbalt\mathbb
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}[FakeBold=4]
%\let\mathbb\mathbbalt

\begin{document}

    \begin{align*}
        v & \in\mathbb{V}\\
        f & \in\mathbb{F}
    \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output without the let command. It is bolded but the font is not computer modern mathbb. I would like the computer modern mathbb font fakebolded

[image: Here]

Comment: What about removing your `\let` commands?

Comment: in that case the mathbb fonts do not remain computer modern fonts. will add it in the post

Comment: This is exactly the same as your other questions, you need to use OpenType Font for Fakebold, you are using the 8bit type1 fonts as you explicitly prevented unicode-math supplying a suitable font.

Comment: I have used both computer modern and latin modern math font in `setmathfont`. But the output is still same.

Comment: Updated OP to reflect your point. output still same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're loading `amsfonts` and `amssymb`.

With your `\let` commands you're reverting to the blackboard bold letters from `amsfonts` that obviously don't respect the `FakeBold=2` option.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{fontspec}


\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Regular.otf}[FakeBold=10]

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
v\in\mathbb{V}\\
f\in\mathbb{F}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

I used 10 in order to make the bolding more evident.

[image]

Here's the output with `FakeBold=2`:

[image]

In order to limit the bleeding from my eyes, here's the output without `FakeBold`:

[image]

Comment: this is the output I get with your code: https://i.imgur.com/cnwFmhh.png
The second one in OP

Comment: @Masum Apparently we have different versions of NewCMMath. I have version 2.3 (the date in TeX Live is 2020-08-24.

Comment: @Masum Indeed, if I switch to TeX Live 2019, I get the same glyphs as you. But they're fakebolded. Update your TeX system.

Comment: My TeX Live is 2020 version as far as I know. But it seems you are right. In the official document, the computer modern font does look like the actual one whereas the output I am getting is what they call 'X'. See page 17 in this doc: http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/newcomputermodern/newcm-unimath-symbols.pdf

Comment: @Masum If you're on a Unix system, please do from the shell `otfinfo -v $(kpsewhich NewCMMath-Regular.otf)` and report what you get.

Comment: Unfortunately I am on Windows. Although I installed it from theISO texlive2020-20200406.iso here: https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/texlive/Images

Comment: @Masum You should update it: the new version has been released after the ISO image has been made.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113800/discussion-between-masum-and-egreg).