# Mathspec fakebold not working on operators or special symbols

Tags: xetex, mathspec

Another question that sounds similar to this is: [Fakebold not working on mathbb fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/565646/fakebold-not-working-on-mathbb-fonts)

but the issue here is different. Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass[11pt, leqno, a4paper]{amsart}

\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setallmainfonts[FakeBold=4]{Old Standard}

\begin{document}
    \textsc{LEHMER}: \textit{Asymptotic Evaluation of certain Totient Sums.}
    \vskip.5cm
    and 
    \begin{align*}
        N
            & =p^{m(an-1)}(p-1)\sum_{j=0}^{l}p^{m(n-1)}\Delta \Phi_m\Bigl(\frac{x}{p^{n+j}}\Bigr)\\
        \lvert N\rvert
            &  \leqq A_1 \frac{(p-1)}{p^m}x^{mn}\log x \sum_{j=0}^{l}p^{m(n-1)} \ldots\\
            & \leqq A_2 x^{mn}\log \\
        f
            & :\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}
    \end{align*}
    M\H{o}bius function $\mu(n)$. $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{C}$ is an arithmetic function
\end{document}
```

Here is the output: [image]
As you can see, the equal sign, <= operator and mathbb symbols are not bold.

Comment: Why the long umlaut on Möbius? He was German, as far as I know.

Comment: I was testing if it works because with another font I was getting weird output. I don't really have any idea about the accents but I know it's supposed to be the two dots above o, not the slanted one

Comment: OK, just to be sure. Anyway, you should know that `mathspec` is kind of a big hack…

Comment: Off-topic: Into my code of your recent question I have put \textsc{LEHMER}. It is wrong. The correct mode is: \textsc{Lehmer}.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. I knew that already though